# Does Ancestral Spirit revive cards in the same state they were previously?

Tags: hearthstone

Does ancestral spirit revive the card only as it was played on the field? Or is it something else? Such as previous state but full health?

Say I play sunwalker, it gets silenced but I put ancestral spirit on it. When it revives, will it have taunt and divine shield or will it be silenced still?

I'm pretty sure the answer is that it will revive with taunt & divine shield but I wanted to make sure. Also, is there any instances where it will not revive as it was when played? (obviously not including being silenced after using ancestral spirit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ancestral Spirit](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ancestral_Spirit) will basically play the card again, without Battlecry.

If you Ancestral a [Sunwalker](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sunwalker), then yes, it revives with Taunt and Divine Shield. If you Ancestral a [Leeroy](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Leeroy_Jenkins), it'll revive with Charge without giving your opponent Whelps.

This means any buffs or debuffs (like a [Sun Cleric](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shattered_Sun_Cleric) buff) will no longer apply. (Obviously, positional / battlefield buffs like [Dire Wolf Alpha](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Dire_Wolf_Alpha) or [Stormwind Champion](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Stormwind_Champion) still will.)

One minor thing to note that it is possible to Ancestral an enemy minion; that minion will revive on their side. This also happens if your opponent uses [Shadow Madness](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Madness), [Mind Control](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mind_Control), or [Cabal Shadow Priest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Cabal_Shadow_Priest) on a minion on your side affected by Ancestral Spirit.

Comment: Your answer explains it perfectly. One note to clarify: Anything with battlecry will not happen. But if you have a knife juggler out on the field, he will shoot off 1 knife when the minion comes back to life.

Comment: Follow up question: If you faceless manipulator, will it come back as the copied card or as the faceless manipulator?

Comment: It should come back as the copied card. I've had faceless manipulator bounced back to my hand it was the copied card. I believe it counts as the copied card for all intents and purposes. But its probably worth a separate question about the manipulator itself.

Comment: Just for future reference it 100% does come back at the copied card.

Comment: Once Faceless Manipulator copies a card it is now that card for the rest of the game.